# IEx - run Mix "test" task

Tags: testing, elixir, read-eval-print-loop, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I get a bit tired of switching between Tmux panes so I'm trying to just work with `vim` and `iex` rather than entering mix commands into another console.

With that goal in mind, I enter the following into the `iex` console but my tests don't appear to execute:

```
Mix.env(:test)
Mix.Task.reenable "test"
Mix.Task.run "test", []
```

The console output is:

```
iex(52)>Mix.env(:test)
:ok
iex(53)>Mix.Task.reenable "test"
:ok
iex(54)>Mix.Task.run "test", []


Finished in 0.00 seconds
0 tests, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 732638
[#Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>,
 #Function<4.72894143/1 in Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1>]
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to make this work?

Comment: I don't have a pointer to get your unstuck but I did confirm this does work for me, sorry

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, and I resolved with the vim plugin: https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test, it has support for elixir tests

Comment: Were you ever able to sort out a good rhythm for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't really fix the problem but as a workaround you can use

```
Mix.Shell.cmd("mix test", fn _ -> nil end)
```

See [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12.3/Mix.Shell.html#cmd/3)